# WebExtensions: Intercept special protocol links

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, protocols, browser-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'd like to write a simple WebExtension that handles certain types of links. I don't want a system wide protocol handler, it should simply work for websites open in my browser.
So for instance when anything causes a magnet:// link to be opened, I'd like to intercept that so that the WebExtension handles it.
And if possible I'd like to prevent system applications from handling it while the WebExtension is enabled.

At first I thought that I could use registerProtocolHandler:

```
navigator.registerProtocolHandler("magnet", "*%s", "Magnet handler");
```

But I don't think that this would do what I want it to...
My next idea was to use a click event on all a-elements:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a').addEventListener('click', event => {
    let link = event.target.href
    if (link.startsWith('magnet://')) {
        // handle magnet link
        return false
    }
}
```

But that would only work for links that were clicked on. A link that is opened using JavaScript would not be affected, so that wouldn't work either..

Answer (score 2):

I used a trick in an extension to do just that:
Register your protocol handler in the manifest:

```
  "protocol_handlers": [
    {
      "protocol": "magnet",
      "name": "Torrent Control Reloaded Magnet Handler",
      "uriTemplate": "https://torrent-control-reloaded.invalid/%s"
    }
  ]
```

then handle the request as you wish:

```
   browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        (details) => {
            var parser = document.createElement('a');
            parser.href = details.url;
            var magnetUri = decodeURIComponent(parser.pathname).substr(1);
            // do what you want with magnetUri
            return {cancel: true}
        },
        {urls: ['https://torrent-control-reloaded.invalid/*']},
        ['blocking']
    );
```

It's not nice, but it works.
You can find the extension here: https://github.com/Mika-/torrent-control/

Answer (score 1):

Work is underway here to support custom protocol handlers:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1271553

Comment: registerProtocolHandler is already available and works just fine for mailto:, magnet:, irc: etc.  But it's not what I'm looking for as mentioned in the question. registerProtocolHandler can only register a certain protocol to a website.

Comment: But I believe the intention in that bug is to let extensions register handlers at moz-extension:// urls which would allow the handler to be contained within the extension.  I thought that's what you were looking for?